# Azure Mobile Services push notifications fails without any message

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I have to add to our app push notifications. These notifications should be send to concrete devices.

Following code:

```
request.service.push.apns.send('hardcoded token for test purposes', {
    alert: 'This is my message for iOS!',
    expiry: '2015-07-16T19:20+01:00'
}, { success: console.log, error: console.error });
```

It doesn't have any observable effects - it does not send notification, it does not throw any error, it does not log any message.

I'm stuck because Microsoft's documentation doesn't cover these cases.

EDIT:
After two hours in configuration I made that code to log:

```
{ isSuccessful: true,
  statusCode: 201,
  body: '',
  headers: 
   { 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     'content-type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
     server: 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
     date: 'Mon, 22 Dec 2014 13:39:36 GMT' },
  md5: undefined }
```

But it doesn't send notification to application.

Comment: Used this

`push.apns.send(trimtoken, {
                                payload: {
                                    "inAppMessage": "Hi,there is some data: "
                                }
                            });`

Comment: It doesn't work too.

Comment: hi @ginden this my code that is work properly for me.
`push.apns.send(token, {
                               alert : "Toast: " + arrOfIDList[0],
                               badge : 3 ,
                                payload: {
                                    "inAppMessage": "Hi,there is some data " ,
                                    "id" : arrOfIDList[0]
                                }
                            });`